# How do I encrypt (password protect) a PDF without encrypting the metadata?

Tags: encryption, pdf, pdftk

It seems that the encryption provided by `pdftk(1)` is the level supported by Acrobat 5 (I added a password to a PDF file using `pdftk` then opened it in Acrobat Pro 9 and examined the security settings; "Acrobat 5-compatible" was the selected setting).

However, I want to encrypt a PDF yet leave the metadata as clear text.  It appears that jPDFTweak can do this ([jPDF Tweak Documentation](http://jpdftweak.sourceforge.net/manual/index.html) and scroll to the Encrypt/Sign section and the screenshot shows a checkbox for "Do not encrypt metadata").  (**Edit:** Yep, tried jPDFTweak and it does work.)

I have a few dozen PDFs to process (repeatedly!) and I need a command line interface, so I'd prefer to use `pdftk` for this (the rest of my workflow uses `pdftk`).

Any ideas?